# How to prevent Emacs from opening error buffer

Tags: error-handling

I got someone ask this question:

> How can I prevent errors that should really just be a bell or flashing
>   screen not open a window with an error?

Comment: What sorts of errors are you looking to prevent from opening a new window? All errors? Just some?

Comment: @zck I think he wanted to disable all kinds of error buffers from being opened in Emacs.

Answer (score 5):

Not exactly sure what the context is or what you mean.

If by "open a window with an error" and "opening error buffer" you mean opening the debugger in buffer `*Backtrace*`, then set variable `debug-on-error` to `nil` to prevent that. The error message will then simply be shown in the echo area.

Variable `visible-bell` controls whether a bell (ding) sound is heard or the frame is flashed ("visible bell").

Comment: Thanks. `debug-on-error` should be nil by default. But I don't know in what context it pops up for him. `semantic-mode` still pops backtrace, even if `debug-on-error` is nil; maybe this is the case, or some other packages do this. `visible-bell` seems only to flash frame, but `ring-bell-function` controls how to ring the bell.

Comment: `visible-bell` controls whether function `ding` rings the bell or flashes the frame.

Comment: `debug-on-error` is `nil` by default, of course. But it being non-`nil` is likely what is invoking the debugger on an error. And it is of course possible to invoke the debugger (`*Backtrace*`) explicitly, either related to an error or not. As far as I know, you cannot prevent code from opening the debugger. You can, however, prevent it from *automatically* opening on an error that is *not handled*, using `nil` `debug-on-error`.

Comment: @TuDo it seems like you don't exactly know what the error the user wants to stop is. It might be useful to figure that out -- if it's just one package ("when I compile c code, I'd like errors in the minibuffer"), then we can look at that package to figure out what to do.

Comment: @zck: +1. And non-`nil` `debug-on-error` is typically a good way to find out what the error is and where it is being called. ;-)